# Comic where multiple Supergirls flew in a line

Tags: story-identification, dc, comics, supergirl

A few years ago, I read a DC comic that had a multiverse in it and there was a scene that had a whole bunch (four or five) of Supergirls flying in a line formation like the jets at the beginning of this video:

If I remember right, the supergirls were in formation almost mirror image to the image of the planes in the video -- they were all flying facing the right, and the top girl was the most right, the others sliding more left as they went down something like this:

```
        111>
      222>
    333>
  444>
555>
```

I think that each Supergirl was from another universe. Maybe one of them was [Powergirl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_Girl).

What comic was this?

Comment: A "few" years ago? Also, is this the only thing you remember about the comic? Were they wearing the same outfit? Were they fighting?

Comment: I love your name, Doctor W! A few years is at least three, maybe five years ago. They were definitely not wearing the same costume -- I'm like 90% sure that they were from different universes. I'm pretty sure they were flying to fight somewhere, but I don't remember the story exactly.

Comment: Was it a new comic then?

Comment: It probably was a new comic then. I'm pretty sure the drawings looked more modern, but maybe they were recolored old ones? But probably a newish comic. I borrowed them from my roommate who was reading a lot of comics at the time, and which comics I borrowed and read gets a little blurry.

Comment: How many of them? Not [five](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/b5/67/1d/b5671d267c908ac1cf40360c8b6b236a.jpg)?

Comment: I didn't realize that the youtube video would look like that. If I remember right, the supergirls were in formation almost mirror image to the planes that I see now -- they were all flying facing the right, and the top girl was the most right, the others sliding more left as they went down. There were at least four, maybe five of them.

Comment: I don't think it was that picture, Gallifreyan. Thanks though.

Comment: What comic is that from? Maybe it was a different picture in the same comic.

Comment: Did your comic have any characters from that picture in it?

Comment: It had four or five supergirls, so probably. That's not the exact picture i was thinking of but maybe its the right comic. what comic was that?

Comment: I have no idea, I just found it while randomly googling.

Comment: You're good with google, then. I couldnt find anything usefull.

Comment: Hmm. could it have been one of the Grant Morrison *MULTIVERSITY* titles? The time frame would be about right, 2-3 years ago. The next best possibility I can think of would be much older - the last few issues of Peter David's run on *SUPERGIRL* (specifically 75-80, circa 2003). And as far as I can tell, that only had two Supergirls - the "Matrix" Supergirl (current at DC from 1988-2003), and a version of "Kara Zor_El" as she first appeared in the 1950's. Peter apparently had plans for involving Power Girl and changing the book's title to *SUPERGIRLS*, but DC went another way.

Comment: I don't think so, @RDFozz. I don't remember the Gentry at all (from wikipedia's synopsis on multiversity), and i have never seen that rabbit thing from the cover one the wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Multiversity

Comment: Thank you for the possibility, tho i appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

The best example I have been able to find is from **Superman/Batman #24**

> Bizarro assembles the Pre-Crisis Kara Zor-El, Post-Crisis Kara Zor-El, Linda Danvers, Cir-El, and Power Girl to rescue Superman. [Wikipedia-Alternate Versions of Supergirl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_versions_of_Supergirl#Alternative_storylines)

[image: Image from Superman/Batman #24]

[Gallifreyan's image](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161848/looking-for-a-comic-where-multiple-supergirls-flew-in-a-line#comment427614_161848) is likely from the same issue (they appear to be drawn the same).

[image]